# How to render Mandelbrot Set faster?

Tags: python, tkinter, mandelbrot

I'm currently drawing the Mandelbrot set pixel by pixel with PhotoImage and tkinter. I'm using basically the algorithm directly with no modifications. Are there methods to make the calculation faster? Maybe filling in large areas of color quickly, or precalcuating constants?

Part of the code:

```
ITERATIONS = 50
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 600
CENTER = (-.5, 0)
DIAMETER = 2.5

def mandel(c):
    z = 0
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        z = z**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i     
    return ITERATIONS

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
img = PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.create_image((WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), image=img, state="normal")


real = CENTER[0] - 0.5 * DIAMETER
imag = CENTER[1] - 0.5 * DIAMETER

def color(i):
    colors = ("#0000AA", "#88DDFF", "#FF8800", "#000000")
    if i == ITERATIONS:
        return colors[-1]
    else:
        choice = (i//2) % len(colors)
    return colors[choice]

for x in range(WIDTH):
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        i = mandel(complex(real, imag))

        img.put(color(i), (x, HEIGHT-y))

        imag += DIAMETER / HEIGHT
    imag = CENTER[1] - 0.5 * DIAMETER
    real += DIAMETER / WIDTH

mainloop()
```

Comment: Would you kindly add here, and all respected StackOverflow Answer authors in their respective proposals, state your initial **code-execution time [usec]** ( + respective solution's, where proposed ), to set a benchmark and base for whatever a faster approach has to beat and what is your expected acceleration treshold -- how much faster you want the process to get? Thanks for your kinde re-consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting one pixel at a time is likely the main source of the slowdown. Instead of calling put for each pixel, computer a whole row of pixels, or an entire matrix of pixels, and then call put one time at the end of the loop.

You can find an example here, among other places: https://web.archive.org/web/20170512214049/http://tkinter.unpythonic.net:80/wiki/PhotoImage#Fill_Many_Pixels_at_Once

Comment: Best results by far, other than rewriting with numpy

Comment: Coming back to this question years later, I realize that writing out to an image file (either something simple like ppm or with pillow converting numpy array to image) would be even faster than trying to use tk to render.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code, it draws a 640x480 Mandelbrot in 8-9 seconds.

It does up to 256 iterations per pixel, uses a color map list, 'puts' only once to `PhotoImage` and doesn't rely on symetry, so it could show any zoomed area of the set.

It's a pity that Tkinter doesn't allow access to the raster information of `PhotoImage` as a buffer and that the clumsy string is required.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage,NW,mainloop 
from time import clock

def mandel(kx,ky):
  """ calculates the pixel color of the point of mandelbrot plane
      passed in the arguments """

  global clr
  maxIt = 256
  c = complex(kx, ky)
  z = complex(0.0, 0.0)
  for i in range(maxIt):
      z = z * z + c
      if abs(z) >= 2.0:
         return (255-clr[i],0,0)
  return(0,0,0)

def prepare_mdb(xa,xb,ya,yb):
    """ pre-calculates coordinates of the mandelbrot plane required for each
      pixel in the screen"""

    global x,y,xm,ym
    xm.clear
    ym.clear
    xm=[xa + (xb - xa) * kx /x  for kx in range(x)]
    ym=[ya + (yb - ya) * ky /y  for ky in range(y)]


x=640
y=480
#corners of  the mandelbrot plan to display  
xa = -2.0; xb = 1.0
ya = -1.5; yb = 1.5
#precalculated color table
clr=[ int(255*((i/255)**12)) for i in range(255,-1,-1)]
xm=[]
ym=[]
prepare_mdb(xa,xb,ya,yb)

#Tk 
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width = x, height = y, bg = "#000000")
t1=clock()
img = PhotoImage(width = x, height = y)
canvas.create_image((0, 0), image = img, state = "normal", anchor = NW)
pixels=" ".join(("{"+" ".join(('#%02x%02x%02x' % mandel(i,j) for i in xm))+"}" for j in ym))
img.put(pixels)
canvas.pack()
print(clock()-t1)
mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a modest increase in speed (but not enough to offset the difference between a compiled language and an interpreted one), you can precalculate some of the values.

Right now, you're calculating `DIAMETER / HEIGHT` once per inner loop, and `CENTER[1] - 0.5 * DIAMETER` as well as `DIAMETER / WIDTH` once per outer loop. Do this beforehand.

`len(colors)` also won't change and can be replaced by a constant. In fact, I'd probably write that function as

```
def color(i):
    if i == ITERATIONS:
        return "#000000"
    else:
        return ("#0000AA", "#88DDFF", "#FF8800", "#000000")[(i//2) % 4]
        # are you sure you don't want ("#0000AA", "#88DDFF", "#FF8800")[(i//2) % 3] ?
```

Also, `x**2` is slower than `x*x` (because the `x**y` operator doesn't shortcut for the trivial case of `y==2`), so you can speed that calculation up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Pure python is not that fast for numeric code. The easiest way to speed things up would be to use PyPy. If that is not fast enough, vectorize your algorithms using numpy. If that is still not fast enough, use Cython, or consider rewriting it in C.

Answer (score 1):

Most time is spent in the inner loop in mandel().  `z*z` instead of `z**2` had a slight effect.  There is not much else to speed up there that I can see.  Removing constants from other loops had little effect, though I tend to prefer doing so.  Choosing ITERATIONS so that `ITERATIONS//2 % len(colors) == len(colors)-1`, as in `46 //2 % 4 == 3`, allows simplification of the code.  Exploiting symmetry around the x-axis cuts time in half.  Starting imag at 0 avoids the roundoff error of 300 subtractions from +/- DIAMETER / 2 and  results in a clean center line in the image.

```
from tkinter import *

ITERATIONS = 46
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 601, 601  # odd for centering and exploiting symmetry
DIAMETER = 2.5

start = (-.5 - DIAMETER / 2, 0)  # Start y on centerline
d_over_h = DIAMETER / HEIGHT
d_over_w = DIAMETER / WIDTH

def mandel(c):
    z = 0
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        z = z*z + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i     
    return ITERATIONS

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
img = PhotoImage(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.create_image(((WIDTH+1)//2, (HEIGHT+1)//2), image=img, state="normal")


real, imag = start

colors = ("#0000AA", "#88DDFF", "#FF8800", "#000000")
ncolors = len(colors)
yrange = range(HEIGHT//2, -1, -1)  # up from centerline
ymax = HEIGHT - 1

for x in range(WIDTH):
    for y in yrange:
        i = mandel(complex(real, imag))
        color = colors[i//2 % ncolors]
        img.put(color, (x, y))
        img.put(color, (x, ymax - y)) 
        imag += d_over_h
    imag = start[1]
    real += d_over_w

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers in python can be slow, especially if you call `abs(x)` every iteration. Representing the complex number with c_r and c_i, for real and imaginary parts, reduces the number of calculations you do every iteration.

```py
def mandel(c):
    z = 0
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        z = z**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i     
    return ITERATIONS
```

instead of `z = 0`, replace it with `z_r,z_i=0,0`
we also have to change c in the parameters.
Now we have:

```py
def mandel(c_r,c_i):
    z_r = 0
    z_i = 0
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        z = z**2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i     
    return ITERATIONS
```

Instead of using `abs(z) > 2`, we can now use `z_r * z_r + z_i + z_i > 4`
Also, we replace `z**2 + c` with a new version using our new variables
(Know that (a+bi)^2 = a^2 - b^2 + 2abi

```py
def mandel(c_r,c_i):
    z_r = 0
    z_i = 0
    z_r_squared = 0
    z_i_squared = 0
    for i in range(ITERATIONS):
        z_r_squared = z_r * z_r
        z_i_squared = z_i * z_i
        z_r = z_r_squared - z_i_squared + c_r
        z_i = 2 * z_r * z_i + c_i

        if z_r_squared + z_r_squared > 4:
            return i     
    return ITERATIONS
```

Finally, you have to change where the mandelbrot function is called, so

```py
i = mandel(complex(real, imag))
```

becomes

```
i = mandel(real, imag)
```

Comment: Can you please time your code? I am getting a slowdown by 2 times when using your version of `mandel` instead of OP's.

Comment: My apologies. This is a very bad answer and it doesn't answer OP at all. a quick test shows my method was 6x slower!

Comment: Btw I found another solution (you can change your answer to it). Using the `numba` library, all you have to do is add `from numba import jit` and then use `@jit` before defining the function. It makes the code run 10 times faster on my computer :D

Comment: That's a good point! I used `@jit` on both functions, and now the OP code is more than 10x slower. Thanks for the tip