# Cartesian coordinate system for tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am interested in animating some geometric algorithms I recently learned 
in Python using a good Gui toolkit such as tkinter or wxPython.

While reading some tkinter tutorials one of the odd things (well at least for a graphics newbie like me) is that the coordinate system used for positioning objects is not the standard cartesian coordinate system, where the origin would be, say, at the center of the screen, and the X-coordinates increase to the right and Y-coordinates increase upwards.

For tkinter the origin is at the top left corner and X-coordinates increase to the right and Y-coordinates decrease downward. Can I make tkinter use the cartesian system as in the previous paragraph?

The final goal is to make an interactive program, where I create a window, with cartesian X,Y axes , the user inputs points using mouse-clicks and then construction of a geometric object such as the convex hull of the points is animated on the same canvas.

Comment: This coordinate system is natural in computer. (probably) It is used in most languages and GUIs.

Comment: One way or another, you have to translate between your cartesian coordinates and pixel coordinates.  This is a standard problem in computer graphics and is discussed in books and on the web.  Note that you only need 2D translation and scaling, no rotation.  So each coordinate transforms independently and no matrixes are needed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447915/how-to-render-mandelbrot-set-faster/26448574#26448574 for how I did this for plotting the mandelbrot set.