# Trying to plot Mandelbrot set - no matter what, always get plain black image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

First, here's the code I have:

```
from PIL import Image as im
import numpy as np 

def mandelbrot_iteration(c): 
    iters = 0
    while abs(c)<2 and iters<200:
        c=c**2+c
        iters+=1
    return iters

HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 500

diag = im.new('L',(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pix = diag.load()

x_pts = np.arange(-2,2,4/WIDTH)  
y_pts = np.arange(-2,2,4/HEIGHT)

for x in x_pts:
    for y in y_pts:
        pix[x+2,y+2]=mandelbrot_iteration(complex(x,y))

diag.save("Fractal.png")
```

I thought this was quite straight forward. I see how many interations each point on a grid of complex numbers takes to grow past an abs. value of 2 and plot these values as a colour at each point (with 200 being the cutoff, assuming the sequence doesn't diverge). In the range specified, there should definitely be some non-trivial things going on, but no matter what I try, the image made is plain black.

Also this method of generating images has almost zero documentation. I've searched a lot, and this:

> im.load()
>
> Allocates storage for the image and loads it from the file (or from
>   the source, for lazy operations). In normal cases, you don’t need to
>   call this method, since the Image class automatically loads an opened
>   image when it is accessed for the first time.
>
> (New in 1.1.6) In 1.1.6 and later, load returns a pixel access object
>   that can be used to read and modify pixels. The access object behaves
>   like a 2-dimensional array, so you can do:
>
> pix = im.load() print pix[x, y] pix[x, y] = value
>
> Access via this object is a lot faster than getpixel and putpixel

Is *everything* that I can find about it (no examples out there either), which is very frustrating. I imagine the line pix[x+2,y+2] is at fault. The '+2's are there to stop the "out of range" errors, but, having tried some examples, I have no idea what it does with input numbers to generate a colour. I did find that 'L' when the image is created should make a greyscale image, but no idea what range pix[x,y] expects or anything. Everything came out black...

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but: What color mode is your target image in? What one did you expect?

Comment: @RadLexus Somewhere I found that 'L' in the im.new() should be 8bit pixels, between black and white. So greyscale. I was expecting lighter colours for pixels which diverge quicker. I was expecting black at the points which converge.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The docs say for "L" that "8-bit greyscale. 0 means black, 255 means white." - and your range should be at least 0..199 then. Test by printing out the return values of your `mandelbrot` function. If it's all zeroes, the error is in there. Otherwise, it's in the image generation.

Comment: mandelbrot iteration should be z=0, while abs(z)<2, z=z**2+c

Comment: @RadLexus Ran it with a snippet counting values. The mandelbrot function returns numbers >100 36629 times, and <=100 163371 times. So.. it's not all zeroes!

Comment: Indeed. I tested it the way I proposed and since the numbers *appeared* okay, I looked further on :) But as @hcs pointed out, there was an implementation error in your routine. Fortunately, that fix was easy.

Comment: This question is effectively a duplicate of others, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447915/how-to-render-mandelbrot-set-faster.  See my answer there for code that works, with a comment on centering.  Just use `pix[x,y]` instead of `img.put(x,y)`. You should iterate through exact integer pixel coordinates for plotting and convert to them to world coordinates for the mandelbrot iteration.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: the target of the program is the same, no question about that. But FireGarden wrote this code by themself, and encountered a unique problem while doing so. Saying "here is some code that works", without at the very least telling why the original code did not work, won't teach FG to be a better programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is your *scale* is off.

In this line `pix[x+2,y+2]=...`, with your ranges for `x` and `y`, the only pixels that are being drawn are `0..4`. Since the last few pixels drawn are black, the entire top left 4x4 square is black (and the rest is 0 – also black – by default, for a new image).

That can be fixed like this:

```
from PIL import Image as im
import numpy as np 

def mandelbrot_iteration(c): 
    iters = 0
    while abs(c)<2 and iters<200:
        c=c**2+c
        iters+=1
    return iters

HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 500

diag = im.new('L',(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pix = diag.load()

x_pts = np.arange(-2,2,4.0/WIDTH)  
y_pts = np.arange(-2,2,4.0/HEIGHT)

for x in x_pts:
    for y in y_pts:
        pix[WIDTH*(x+2)/4.0,HEIGHT*(y+2)/4.0]=mandelbrot_iteration(complex(x,y))

diag.show()
```

although the result is not yet a good Mandelbrot...

[image: mandelsmorgasbord]

With hcs' comment "mandelbrot iteration should be z=0, while abs(z)<2, z=z**2+c" applied, you'd use this code

```
from PIL import Image as im
import numpy as np 

def mandelbrot_iteration(c): 
    iters = 0
    z = 0
    while abs(z)<2 and iters<200:
        z=z**2+c
        iters+=1
    return iters

HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 500

diag = im.new('L',(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pix = diag.load()

x_pts = np.arange(-2,2,4.0/WIDTH)  
y_pts = np.arange(-2,2,4.0/HEIGHT)

for x in x_pts:
    for y in y_pts:
        pix[WIDTH*(x+2)/4.0,HEIGHT*(y+2)/4.0]=mandelbrot_iteration(complex(x,y))

# diag.show()
diag.save("Fractal.png")
```

and lo and behold, a true Mandelbrot pops up:

[image: Correct Mandelbrot]

Comment: Well, that's that sorted then! Thank you very much for your (and @hcs 's) help!